# How to remove "<", ">" and all text between them in a string?

Tags: php

I have these sample strings

```
"<textcolor='red'><h1>FAILED - NOT ENOUGH STEPS PERFORMED</h1></textcolor>"
"<b style='color:white; background-color:red'>FAILED</b>"
```

and I'd like to get rid of all the HTML formatting there so I get this

```
"FAILED - NOT ENOUGH STEPS PERFORMED"
"FAILED"
```

I guess getting rid of the lessthan and greaterthan signs and anything between them would do. I know I could use preg_replace for this but I'm not exactly sure what format to use.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
$code = "<textcolor='red'><h1>FAILED - NOT ENOUGH STEPS PERFORMED</h1></textcolor>";
echo strip_tags($code);
```

The code mentioned supra would output:

```
FAILED - NOT ENOUGH STEPS PERFORMED
```

Without any styling whatsoever, unless that styling is inherited from the parent element.

The [strip_tags function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is the easiest and most effective method to remove all the tags in HTML. The purpose of `preg_replace` is to remove or change a wider variety of symbols, such as changing anything starting with an 'a' or something, while strip_tags' purpose is specifically to sanitize HTML input - what you most likely need to do anyway.

Comment: thanks! this is a **lot** easier than fiddling around with regex patterns all day!

Answer (score 1):

[strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) would seem to be the way to go. preg_replace might be able to do it but it would be rather complicated to make it reliable.